# Solving a differential equation using guess and verify

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve for an explicit expression of $f(x)$ where $f$ satisfies

$$f(x)=x-\frac{x}{n-1}f'(x),\tag{1}$$

where $n$ is a constant. The hint says that we can guess

$$f(x)=ax^b,$$

so that

$$f'(x)=abx^{b-1}.$$

Substituting the guessed form into $(1)$, we get

$$ax^b=x-\frac{1}{n-1}abx^b.\tag{2}$$

I know that the final solution is $b=1$ and $a=\frac{n-1}{n}$.

My questions are

1. How to get from $(2)$ to the solution. In particular, how do we know that $b=1$ (I'm able to solve for $a$ from there)?
2. Is there another way to get the solution directly from $(1)$ without guessing and verifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question, we can use an [integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor):

$$ f'(x) + \frac{n-1}{x} f(x) = n-1 $$

Multiplying by $I(x) = x^{n-1}$, we get

$$ f'(x)x^{n-1} + (n-1) x^{n-2} f(x) = (n-1) x^{n-1} $$

Simplifying the left hand side using product rule:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} (f(x) x^{n-1}) = (n-1) x^{n-1} $$

Integrating both sides then lets us solve for $f(x)$

$$ f(x) x^{n-1} = \frac{n-1}{n} x^n + C$$
$$ f(x) = \frac{n-1}{n} x + \frac{C}{x^{n-1}}$$

Comment: You need to be a bit careful when $n=0$ as we end up with logs.  I'll leave the solution for $n=0$ up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You get $b=1$ because that is the only value of $b$ for which the equation is an identity over $x$.  You then are able to solve for $a$.